# angularjs quiz save result to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

[ASK] I make a quiz that require a result that can be save to my database 
oke here the code that i tried to save the result from that quiz

```
$scope.questions.forEach(function (q, index) {
    answers.push({ 'QuizId': $scope.quiz.Id, 'QuestionId': q.Id, 'Answered': q.Answered });         
    $http.post('http://localhost/server_log/insert.php', answers).success(function (data) { alert(data);    
    });
});
```

and here is the insert.php

```
<?php  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dataujian");  
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  

    $answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Answered);       


        $query = "INSERT INTO nilai (jawaban) VALUES ('$answer')";  
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        echo true;
?>
```

But when i try to submit it nothing happen, it there anything wrong with my code.

Comment: look at your developer console and check for errors on the query and error reporting.

Comment: You're calling `answers.push`. So `answers` must be an array, but you're trying to access the value directly on `$data`. Try `$data[0]->Answered` instead.

Comment: you're right the answer array... got it... let me try first

Answer (score 0):

> it there anything wrong with my code.

There are a few problems with your code. Build in small pieces so you can test as you go.

- One problem is that you're doing a new HTTP POST request for each answer.
- Another problem is that you're not validating your inputs on the PHP side, so you don't know what `php://input` actually contains or whether `json_decode` was successful
- Another problem is that you're not checking for errors when you run your DB query so you have no clue whether the query was executed successfully

You say:

> when i try to submit it nothing happen

This is vague. Does it mean that AngularJS doesn't make any request?  That PHP doesn't respond?

Comment: the php doesn't respond cause i try push array into one row table... ok i will try to divide small pieces first ... thank for the tip ...